# Django - Get all the fields from a model represented as a List of Strings where order is retained

Tags: django, python-2.7

For example,

```
Class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

>>> func_do_stuff(MyModel)
>>> ['field1', 'field2']
```

The list of strings also has to maintain order, so `["field2", "field1"]` doesn't suffice.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: order condition

Answer (score 0):

```
MyModel._meta.get_all_field_names()
```

[Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/meta/).

Comment: Sorry but I updated the question. Any chance you know the answer to the question?

Comment: I don't understand, what are you trying to do with the ordering?

Comment: Like ordering of definition in the Class. Field1 is defined before FIeld2 and I want it to appear in the list before Field2.

Comment: I understand what you mean by order, I don't get why do you need the ordering.

Comment: Sorry, misread your comment. I'm pulling data from an external server so the order of the columns have to be maintained so I can map a section of the row to the corresponding column.

Comment: That's not possible at this point. What is going to happen if you don't obey the order?

Comment: Then values get mapped to different fields. I'm using a library for reading the SQL values.

Comment: That's very bad practice using index to figure out database fields. If they insert another column, your application just breaks. You should always explicitly using names for column matching and don't assume that they are in order.